# CocoaPods and Target Dependencies

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods

I recently inherited an old iOS 5 multi-project that have a *xcworkspace* that have the following projects:

1. **Communications project:** contains some reusable code and frameworks, defines a target as static library.
2. **Client project:** iOS client project that has nested a symbolic link to the **1.** project and includes a *Target Dependency* to it.
3. **Manager project:** same structure as described for **2.**.

**Note:** to clarify the meaning of *static library* and *nested projects*, please have a look to http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial (Method 2: Subprojects).

I am trying to add CocoaPods for the 3rd project, but I can't modify the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` and `OTHER_LDFLAGS` values because they are use to link the static library.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it is as simple as add manually the `$(inherited)` option to `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` without deleting the existing static library headers dir.